# annoymousFunciton.call(this) vs annoymousFunciton(this)

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```
(function(r) {
  var ExcelApp;
  ExcelApp = (function() {
    ....
  }).call(this);
  return r.ExcelApp = ExcelApp;
})(this);
```

I come across this code and wonder why it has to do `.call(this)`, is it equivalent to the code below on any situation?

```
(function(r) {
  var ExcelApp;
  ExcelApp = (function() {
    ....
  })(this);
  return r.ExcelApp = ExcelApp;
})(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not the same

The first one changes `this` context inside the function

E.g.

```js
fun.call({
  x: 3
})

function fun() {
  console.log(this.x) // 3
}
```

The second passes `this` as an argument

E.g.

```js
fun({
  x: 3
})

function fun() {
  console.log(this.x) // undefined
}
```